# MySQL Howto insert values from two tables into one

Tags: mysql

Howto insert values from two tables (`wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) into one (`wp_linkz`)?

I have 2 tables

## 1 wp_posts

- (ID,post_name,post_type)
- 1,first,article
- 2,second,urls
- 3,third,article
- 4,forth,urls

## 2 wp_postmeta

- (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
- 1,the_article,1000
- 2,the_url,google.com
- 3,the_article,3000
- 4,the_url,bing.com

The result should look like this

## 3 wp_linkz

- (id,name,url)
- 2,second,google.com
- 4,forth,bing.com

ID (from wp_post) is the same with post_id (from wp_postmeta).

I want to insert in `wp_links` the `id` (ID only for those with post_type=urls), `name` (`post_nam` only for those with `post_type=urls`) and `url` (`meta_value` only for those with `meta_key=the_url`)

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried a lot of combinations. On is INSERT INTO `wp_linkz`(`id`, `name`) SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `ID`, `post_name` FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'urls'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this query:

```
INSERT INTO wp_linkz (id, name, url)
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_name, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM
  wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
  ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
     AND wp_posts.post_type = 'urls'
     AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'the_url'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75ca0/1).

Comment: Yes. Use it, it works. Here's a SQLFiddle for @fthiella code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac9aa/1

Comment: Tested fiddle, tested on local server and it works. Thanks a lot.